# Return one value from SQL database using PHP

Tags: php

just wondering is there any way that I can return one value from my SQL database? Basically I am writining a website for my A level ICT coursework.
The website must allow posts to be made users and these posts must be stored in a table and then can be viewed by clicking on them
So far I have created a registration form and log in script to authenticate the session and delegate permission levels to users, I have created scripts which post threads to my database and have another script in place to store the data in the table
Now I wish to be able to view my posts when I click on them
So far my script is as follows

```
    <?php include_once('scripts/session_a.php') ; ?>
<?php include_once('scripts/connection.php') ; ?>


<?php


            $strSQL = "SELECT description FROM posts WHERE description=description";
            $result = mysql_query($strSQL) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            echo $row['description'];


?>
```

and this script is called from

```
   <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Project : Absolute Beginners log in system ///////////
    // Purpose : A2 Level Coursework for ICT ////////////////
    // Teacher : Mr L Hawkins ///////////////////////////////
    // Student : Alex Sims //////////////////////////////////
    // Candidate No. : 4173 /////////////////////////////////
    // Centre No : 27168 ////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

    <?php include_once('includes/header.php') ; ?>
    <?php include_once('includes/posts-header.php') ;?>

    <div> <!-- Main Wrapper -->
        <div class="Post Head"/><!-- Start Page -->
            <name="Post" id="Post"/>
            <h2>Absolute Beginners Forum</h2>




        <div name="postname" id="postname"/>    <!--PHP SCRIPT FEEDS NAME DATE AND AUTHOR HERE -->
                <label></label>

                <?php include('scripts/echo_test.php');?>

        </div>


        <div name="content" id="content"/>     <!-- PHP SCRIPT FEEDS CONTENT HERE -->

                <?php include('scripts/get_post_content.php')?>

        </div>

    </div><!-- End board-->







</div><!--End of page-->






</div> <!-- Main Wrapper Ends -->
<?php
```

a screenshot can be seen here of what I was trying to describe

http://gyazo.com/a8cfda3735c8bf2fd26b3b1c70fab191

Hopefully this generates a better understanding of my problem.

Thanks

Alex.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Do you want to show all posts created by the logged in user, or something else? Also, can we please see your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `WHERE description=description` you need to put something like `WHERE id=$someid`. this way you grab only the record matching a certain primary key id field. you would want to pass $someid to the page via a GET variable in the link most likely. you could also ad `LIMIT 1` at the end to make sure the query only grabs one.